# Changing precision digits of "/usr/bin/time" profiler in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, time, profiler, user-profile, archlinux

I would like to know if /usr/bin/time supports more precisions digits than 2? i.e. when I run:

```
/usr/bin/time -f %U ls
```

it gives me : `0.00`, is there any way to increase the digits ?

Secondly, although time refers to /usr/bin/time in my system, but their outputs are different, why is that ? i.e.

```
/usr/bin/time -f %U ls
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.03elapsed 23%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3104maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+259minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

BUT

```
$time ls
real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.008s
```

while I have:

```
$which time
/usr/bin/time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no chance to increase the precision. Sorry for the short answer, but I will say a few words to the second question.

While you have the program `time` installed at `/usr/bin/time` (`which` shows this), there is also a bash builtin with the same name. `bash` will use a builtin in favour of a binary unless you specify the whole path to the binary.

Comment: `/usr/bin/time` is a binary, but your shell also has the time builtin (and uses it in favour of the binary unless you specify the full path to binary) I'm not sure why the binary produces that output.. I'm investigating

Comment: @Amir There is not much to say. The binary just has a lower precision than the bash builtin, you can't do much, except of using the builtin. I wasn't aware of this before you've asked here :) +1 for the question..

Comment: btw, do you know why I can NOT redirect the output of `$time` to a file ?

Comment: you can: `time COMMAND 2> output.file` . Output goes to stdout

Comment: Ok, then it is related to the builtin behaviour.. You can use `/usr/bin/time -p command 2> output.txt` but having lower precision.

Comment: Yes, that was what I using and at some points of my explorations i am seeing these 0.00 !! definitely i need another profile for a higher one